# hyper Link on Text in react

Tags: reactjs

**How to make a Link on text i tried please help what i am doing wrong**

> Signup is Component when i click Join Now text the only path change 
>   e.g Signup/

```
<BrowserRouter>
     <Link to="/Signup"> Join now</Link>
</BrowserRouter>
```

> Error
>
> ```
> index.js:2178 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>.
>     in a (created by Link)
>     in Link (at Login.js:205)
>     in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
>     in BrowserRouter (at Login.js:203)
>     in a (at Login.js:123)
>     in MyLink (created by WithStyles(MyLink))
>     in WithStyles(MyLink) (at Login.js:200)
>     in p (created by Typography)
>     in Typography (created by WithStyles(Typography))
>     in WithStyles(Typography) (at Login.js:197)
>     in div (created by Paper)
>     in Paper (created by WithStyles(Paper))
>     in WithStyles(Paper) (created by Card)
>     in Card (created by WithStyles(Card))
>     in WithStyles(Card) (at Login.js:166)
>     in div (at Login.js:164)
>     in Login (created by WithStyles(Login))
>     in WithStyles(Login) (at App.js:35)
>     in div (at App.js:33)
>     in App (created by WithStyles(App))
>     in WithStyles(App) (at index.js:9)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, NavLink} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
<Router>
  <div>
    <ul>
      {/*You can add more links here*/}
      <li><NavLink to='/Signup'>Join Now</NavLink></li>
    </ul>

    <hr/>

    <Route path='/SignUp' component={ComponentName} />
  </div>
)
```

Comment: While this may be the answer, it's best to have some explanatory text saying *why* this is the answer and what the Original Poster can do to discover this answer for themselves.

Comment: Not working just Url path change like : http://localhost:3001/JoinNow what can i do :/ 

Error is : 

index.js:2178 Warning: validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>.